# MobaXterm error: FXApp::openDisplay: unable to open display :0.0

Tags: mobaxterm

I'm trying to open an Abaqus GUI on a cluster. So far I've done this using:

- I log in on the cluster using MobaXterm
- I start a job using:

  > qsub -I - X -l nodes=1:ppn=1,mem=32gb
- I load Abaqus:

  > module load abaqus/2019
- I call the Abaqus GUI:

  > abaqus cae

As said, this used to work until the day before yesterday. Now I get the following error when I try this:

> Abaqus License Manager checked out the following license:
>
> "cae" from Flexnet server the_server
>
> <15 out of 30 licenses remain available>
>
> FXApp::openDisplay: unable to open display :0.0
>
> Fatal Exception: connect
>
> Abaqus Error: Abaqus/CAE Kernel excited with an error

I've looked around and it seems that somebody else had a very similar problem [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=108562), with solutions being posted [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=684936#p684936) (see the figure below). However, the solution specifies '/etc/NetworkManager/nm-system-settings.conf', a file I cannot seem to find (I'm using Windows).

[image: Suggested solution by Wulf Solter]

Does anybody know how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that

> qsub -I - X -l nodes=1:ppn=1,mem=32gb

should be

> qsub -I -X -l nodes=1:ppn=1,mem=32gb

(removing the space between - and X)